# UV4L & USB Webcam - How to change Resolution, FPS etc?

Tags: pi-3, webcam, uv4l

I've been using UV4L for streaming for quite a while now and think it does a brilliant job, especially with the PiCamera 2 module.

I now want to use the program with a USB Webcam as a few days ago I was given another Raspberry Pi 3 board and decided to plug the USB Webcam into it (Logtech C920) and get it running on the UV4L-UVC driver, which was easy peasy, and I had a picture (albeit rather small) streaming on port 8090. Fun!

However, what I'm really not sure about is how you change the default resolution, bitrate, framerate etc.

When using the PiCamera and Raspicam driver on my other board setup everything was *easily* specified in the `uv4l-raspicam.conf` file, but with the `uv4l-uvc.conf` file there are **very few options**, and none of them are to do with image size/quality/rate.

Does anyone know if this is possible to change? I know you can change the resolution on the Webrtc Config page, but this only lasts until the service restarts or a reboot.

Comment: Not much of a solution, but may make things less of a hassle if there is nothing else and you can grok the details: [The web interface is json based](https://www.linux-projects.org/documentation/rest-api/), meaning you could automate changing the settings instead of having to dicker with widgets every time.

Comment: Hmm. Good idea, problem is I wouldn't have a clue how to do that. Just seems odd that there's no config file with the ability to set parameters like these. Oh well....